# How to get current user display image in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, avatar

I have a MOSS 2007 site. I want to display the display image (or avatar, whatever you call it) of the current user.

1. Is it possible without writing a new web part? I don't have any MOSS 2007 installed computer that i can reach, so i can't develop web parts for Sharepointç (Or at at least i think)

Thanks.

P.S. By display image, i'm talking about the image which is uploaded to MySite by the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the info in the /SharedServicesPath/Person.aspx file, we usually do this:
Top of the page:

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="SPSWC" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

At the actual image spot:

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyLoader runat="server" />
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage PropertyName="PictureUrl" ResizeToFit="100" ShowPlaceholder="true" id="PictureUrlImage" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: You're literally my hero. Could you describe that what we did by this?

By the way, you are welcomed to take a look on my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244642/setting-up-a-weekly-digest-in-sharepoint
:)

Comment: I would also like to ask this: How can i get a list of users that have access to my site. Like a data view maybe, so i would display the list as profile pictures on the left and their names at the right.

Comment: That's alot more complicated and most certainly requires actual .net code. The profilepropertyloader works for the current user or the ?accountname=DOMAIN\user querystring parameter