# Setting up a weekly digest in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, alert, digest

I'm currently working on a MOSS 2007 site and i need to set up a "system" which will e-mail all the changes in all the lists and libraries in the site.

I'm new to the Sharepoint world, i wonder if it is possible.

P.S. I have no access to the Central Administration panel. (If it has anything to do with my purpose)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom timer job to do this task.

You could do it in this way:

1. [Create custom timer job feature](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx), set timerjob schedule.
2. On FeatureActivated event add that timerjob to SharePoint and have a [[Persisted] property](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/17/custom-timer-jobs-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-where-to-store-configuration.aspx) like SiteUrl in timerjob, which you could pass in constructor to let timerjob determine with which site to work with.
3. Use [SPWeb.SiteUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteusers.aspx) to get all users in SharePoint.
4. Loop each user, [open new SPSite impersonated as each user](http://blackninjasoftware.com/2009/04/09/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/).
5. On SPSite.RootWeb (SPWeb) execute [GetSiteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getsitedata.aspx) (read community comments for some great examples and explanation on how to use it). Use Query that queries items [where Modified field has value greater than](http://www.wirwar.com/blog/2008/07/30/sharepoint-frustrations-1-the-undocumented-includetimevalue-caml-attribute/) (follow link for important info to query correctly) what you want.
6. Generate html out of your data and [SPUtility.SendMail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx).

There is a [scheduled reminder job](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPScheduedReminders.aspx) feature available. However it works only on 1 List scope. But you can download source code, open RmdJobDefinition class and just see how it works to assist you writing your own class.

Good luck.

Comment: How can i make a custom timer job? I have Visual Studio 2008, Sharepoint SDK and WSS3.0 installed on my pc. If i'm gonna use Visual Studio, what type of "file" will it produce and how will i deploy it on the working farm. A department manages the Sharepoint farm in the client company, for what information i should ask them, their policy for deploying custom timer job? Or custom features? or maybe a web part?

Sorry for too many questions but i've got only 10 hours to the deadline :(

Comment: Sorry, 2 days have passed. However what you need is a WSPBuilder extension (google it) for visual studio for easy package deployment. With it, you just create a new WSPBuilder item that's named Feature With Receiver and is scoped at WebApplication. (it's all written down in the example i linked to). Then you just create a class, exactly as it is within the link where 1'st point leads to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can only setup the alert on a list (or item) basis. In the list you go to Actions => Alerts => When to send alerts => Weekly. I didn't check the Central Admin since you don't have access in your scenario.